# creating a list of float outputs and average over them

Tags: python, list, average

I import my data as arrays in python and put them in a variable like this
`d=np.array(df)`
then I want to print some special values among these arrays by this for loop:

```py
m=0
for m in range(0,len(f)):
    if f[m]>=3 and f[m]<=5 :
    print('phonon2 amplitude is:',a[m])
```

now I want python to put my outputs which are floats in a list and average over them and give me the average, can anyone help me with that? what I get now is like this:
  `9.33226288548927e-06 1.24483816785835e-05 2.4023667055807e-05 1.25956869422604e-05 4.57000694022053e-05 4.76767728683565e-05 5.31031637490364e-05`
but I want like this

```
[9.33226288548927e-06, 1.24483816785835e-05, 2.4023667055807e-05,...]
```

Comment: replace `print()` with code to add the value to a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.append()`:

```
m=0

lst = []
for m in range(0,len(f)):
    if f[m]>=3 and f[m]<=5 :
        lst.append(a[m])

print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a list then print that list. This can all be done in one print statement

```
print([val for val in f if val>=3 and val<=5])
```